# Why is my image splitting up from my div on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

so on a website that I'm creating, I have a wavy type image on top of a div to give the div that kind of wavy effect. And it looks fine on desktop screens:
[Desktop Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QZLw.png)
Although right around 450-pixel width, the image starts to separate from the div, and I'm not entirely sure why it's doing this, there's no bottom margin or anything applied to the img:
[Mobile Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p49bz.png)

If anybody knows a solution, it'd help out a lot. Thanks!

Also, these are the only two CSS styles I've applied to those images. The dimensions are 1000 width by 44 height

```
width: 100%;
height:auto;
```

Comment: show an image or snippet to evaluate and let us see what id happening.

Comment: I put 2 image links on the post, one of it one desktop when it's fine and one on mobile when it's all wonky

Comment: I'm afraid we could only guess at a solution without seeing the relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the div margin-top when the screen size 450px.

```
div{
     margin-top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: Ha, this was actually my exact original solution using media queries and just pushing it down, and it worked great. But, I changed the imgs to svg's just because I feel like it's better to use SVGs for stuff like this. But thanks for the input!